# php7.4 extension amqp installed but not loaded

Tags: php, amqp, php-extension, php-7.4

**I have installed latest version 1.9.4 amqp with php7.4 its installed successfully.
When I am checking it its shown in the phpinfo();**

[image]

**when I am checking through the following command **

```
/etc/apt$ php --ini
PHP Warning:  Module 'amqp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'amqp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.4/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-amqp.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini,
```

**I but when I am checking for loaded extensions its not shown even when I am trying to direct load extension using `dl('amqp.so');` its not loaded.**

I was tried alot but it always give error.

[image]
**can any one plz help me in this.**

Comment: @Rain thanks for the reply I tried with commenting ```extension=amqp.so``` from ```php.ini``` but its not working, still getting the same issue.

Comment: Yes, I did it, but its getting same error.

Comment: I have the same error. Any suggestion ? Thx